# console output of os.system()?

Tags: python, os.system

When calling os.system() in the Interactive Interpreter, you can see what it output's in the console.
But in my case, I needed to change sys.stderr and sys.stdout to an instance of another class and the os.system function is called within an exec statement. The problem is, I don't see what it output's. It does not write to stderr nor to stdout.
So my question: Where does the printed output of os.system() go to ?

Thanks,
Niklas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It goes to either file descriptor 1 or 2, depending on whether it outputs to stdout or stderr. If you need finer control of the output then you should use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: But it doesn't go to stdout or stderr, I don't see it in my output window.  But the subprocess module seems very useful for this ! Thanks !

Comment: But I see, my custom filelike class does not support a fileno() method. Is there a way around it ?

Comment: Create a pipe with `os.pipe()` and use `select` to see if there's any data to read from it.